Remote Desktop keeps reseting password after reboot
I have setup a new install of Ubuntu 24.04.1, and have setup Remote Desktop and set a password.
My problem is after I reboot the PC, the Remote Desktop password gets reset some some random one.
I tried looking up a solution to this, but not able to stop this from happening.
Seeking assistance to hopefully get further guidance to see if this password can be kept from resetting, and how to do it.
Thanks.
